# Add Ubuntu live to another ubuntu+windows system

Tags: grub2, partitioning, live-usb, fdisk

I've got Win7 in a ntfs-partition and lubuntu 12.10 in another one.

```
    **sudo fdisk -l**
    Disco /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 19457 cilindros, 312581808 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x000c119a

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   230688767   115240960    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       230688768   266340351    17825792    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       266342398   312581429    23119516    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       301644014   307068299     2712143    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda6       307068314   312581429     2756558    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda7       266342400   295784447    14721024   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       295786496   301643775     2928640   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Las entradas de la tabla de particiones no están en el orden del disco
```

Before I got Lubuntu I used to create a small partition and with EasyBCD (windows) I used to load a small Linux ISO as live.

Now I'm wondering if I do that in Windows (considering I already modified my grub since I've got Lubunto installing) will I destroy or have problems?

I would like to install this linux-live in sda5. How could I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found [**grub-customizer**](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) which does what I need.